# Set initial ScrollView

Tags: swift, uiscrollview

I want to set "ViewController2" as initial page in the ScrollView but changing `setContentOffset(CGPointMake(0,0), animated: false)` sets the first page as initial, i tried modified it with different numbers but it just messed up the pages, any tips?

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet var scrollView: UIScrollView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    scrollView.bounces = false
    scrollView.pagingEnabled = true
    scrollView.setContentOffset(CGPointMake(0,0), animated: false)
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

}

override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    initScrollView()
}

func initScrollView(){
    let viewController1 = storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ViewController1") as! ViewController1

    viewController1.willMoveToParentViewController(self)
    viewController1.view.frame = scrollView.bounds

    let viewController2 = storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ViewController2") as! ViewController2

    viewController2.willMoveToParentViewController(self)
    viewController2.view.frame.size = scrollView.frame.size
    viewController2.view.frame.origin = CGPoint(x: view.frame.width, y: 0)

    let viewController3 = storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ViewController3") as! ViewController3

    viewController3.willMoveToParentViewController(self)
    viewController3.view.frame.size = scrollView.frame.size
    viewController3.view.frame.origin = CGPoint(x: view.frame.width * 2, y: 0)

    scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: 3 * scrollView.frame.width, height: scrollView.frame.height)

    scrollView.addSubview(viewController3.view)
    self.addChildViewController(viewController3)
    viewController3.didMoveToParentViewController(self)

    scrollView.addSubview(viewController2.view)
    self.addChildViewController(viewController2)
    viewController2.didMoveToParentViewController(self)

    scrollView.addSubview(viewController1.view)
    self.addChildViewController(viewController1)
    viewController1.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to de-select the scroll view inset adjustment... in vc2:

[image: IB Screen]

Comment: Did not change anything, is there some special code to be used along with de-select the scroll view insets?

Answer (score 0):

By putting  `scrollView.setContentOffset(CGPointMake(375,0), animated: false)` in viewDidlayoutSubViews it loads the next view, note that i am using iphone 4,7 inch screen so the width of a viewController is 375. change 375 to the width of your viewController, for example if you wanna load the last page first you do add 375 to 375 and so on..

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    initScrollView()
    scrollView.setContentOffset(CGPointMake(375,0), animated: false)
}
```

Comment: might that become problematic with different size classes?